# React JS and Firebase : Cannot upload image

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Im trying to create a signup form for my website. Im storing the user information on MongoDB and their images on Firebase. When *Signup* button is pressed i get **"POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app/o?name=image.jpg 403"** in the browser's console

I have seen several tutorials on how to upload files to firebase storage using React.js and this is what i tried:

```
const [file , setfile] = useState(null);

const handleClick = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const fileName = new Date().getTime() + file?.name;
    const storage = getStorage(app);
    const StorageRef = ref(storage , fileName);
    
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(StorageRef, file);
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', 

  () =>  {
    // Handle successful uploads on complete
    // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
    //signup() is the node js signup endpoint
      signup(dispatch ,{email , password , username , phonenumber , profile:downloadURL});
      })
    });

  }
```

Image field:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onChange={(e)=>setfile(e.target.files[0])} />
```

If is needed to upload any other part of the code please let me know

Comment: How is `file` defined? Do you have any Security Rules for your Storage default bucket?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec updated my code. Also security rules are ```allow read, write: if false;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments under your question you get a 403 error because your Security Rules prevent any user to upload a file (`allow read, write: if false;`). This is also a point listed by @eugenemusebe in his answer.

You need to adapt your Security Rules in such a way the desired users have the correct access right for writing:

**For example** a user needs to be authenticated to upload an image:

```
service firebase.storage {
  // The {bucket} wildcard indicates we match files in all Cloud Storage buckets
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Match filename
    match /filename {
      allow read: if <condition>;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

More details in the [Security Rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/core-syntax).

---

Note that for testing (and confirming that this is the problem) you can **(temporarily)** open the write access with:

```
service firebase.storage {
  // The {bucket} wildcard indicates we match files in all Cloud Storage buckets
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Match filename
    match /filename {
      allow read: if <condition>;
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```